# Integrating the Dirichlet Kernel using complex analysis

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I was looking at the Dirichlet integral
$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}{(sin((N+\frac{1}{2})x))\over sin(\frac{x}{2})}dx$
and it seems to be possible to integrate using complex analysis. I attempted this using the residue theorem but my understanding of complex analysis is still quite shallow and I was unable to derive an answer. Is there any way to do this integral with complex analysis?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
2\pi I_N
&=\int^{\pi}_{-\pi}\frac{sin(N+\frac12)x}{\sin x/2}dx \\
&= \int^{\pi}_{-\pi}\frac{e^{(N+\frac12)ix}-e^{-(N+\frac12)ix}}{e^{ix/2}-e^{-ix/2}}dx\\
&= \int^{\pi}_{-\pi}\frac{e^{i(N+1)x}-e^{-iNx}}{e^{ix}-1}dx\\
&=\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{z^{N+1}-z^{-N}}{z-1}\frac{dz}{iz}\\
&=2\pi\operatorname*{Res}_{z=0} \frac{z^{N+1}-z^{-N}}{z-1}\frac{1}{z}\\
&= 2\pi\operatorname*{Res}_{z=0} \frac{z^{-N}}{1-z}\frac{1}{z}\\
&=2\pi \\
I_N&\equiv 1\\
\end{align}
$$

Note that the substitution $z=e^{ix}$ is used, and it is assumed that $N\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: Why can we disregard the other pole at z=1?

Comment: @Collon because it is a removable singularity, i.e. taking limit $z\to1$ does not lead to $\infty$.

Comment: Also I made a pretty stupid mistake in writing the question, it should be sin((N+1/2)x) instead of what I wrote. That should change the answer oops. Sorry

Comment: @Collon Uhmm...I did interpret it as $\sin((N+1/2)x)$ and the answer remains legit.